# Как работать с js объектом в PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

у меня есть js объект, который я с помощью json.stringify перевел в:

```
{
  "orderSum": 2300,
  "a_04_ch_kr42": {
    "product": {
      "id": "a_04_ch_kr",
      "category": "demiseason",
      "img": "img/a-04-ch-kr/cholovichi- shkiriani-krosivky1.webp",
      "alt": "Мужские кожаные кроссовки Ads Originals Ozelia",
      "head": "Мужские кожаные кроссовки Ads Originals Ozelia",
      "saleprice": "2300 грн",
      "price": "1890 грн",
      "cta": "купить",
      "color": "коричневый",
      "href": "#"
    }, "quantity": 1, "size": ["42"]
  }
}
```

Как мне из этого js объекта преобразовать в php объект?

Comment: [json-decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)?

Answer (score 3):

**json.stringify** делает из объекта строку. Передайте эту строку в php переменную скрипта.

В PHP скрипте сделайте вызовите **json_decode** и получите объект.

```
json_decode($вашастрока)
```

Также можете получить массив если укажите второй параметр в функцию

```
json_decode($вашастрока, true).
```